# Getting the value of Edittext which created programmatically

Tags: android

In my project ,there is a button which creates Edittex programmatically using foor loop depending on a number that user add,and I don't know how to get the value for each of them.my question is

> How Can I Get The Value Of The Components That I Created
>   Programmatically?

any suggestion well be appreciated.thaks in advance.

```
private void setChoices() {

        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        int marginPixel = 1;
        int marginPixell = 5;
        float densityy =getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int marginDp = (int)(marginPixel * densityy);
        int margin = (int)(marginPixell * densityy);
        params.setMargins(marginDp, margin, marginDp, margin);


        int num= Integer.parseInt(choicesNumberEDT.getText().toString());


        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {

            explanationED= new EditText(this);
            explanationED.setLayoutParams(params);
            layout.addView(explanationED);
            explanationED.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
            explanationED.setHint("أكتب هنا.....");
            explanationED.setTextSize(14);
            explanationED.setId(i);
            float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int paddingDp = (int) (Const.paddingPixel * density);
            explanationED.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#B2E3CC"));
            explanationED.setPadding(paddingDp, paddingDp, paddingDp, paddingDp);

        }


    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't know how to get the value for each of them"? You have int num= Integer.parseInt(choicesNumberEDT.getText().toString()); which gets the number that the user entered.

Comment: i mean for the programmatically created edittext

Comment: You would use explanationED.getText().toString; just like you did a few lines above

Comment: explanationED.getText().toString; this line code will give me the value of the last created edittext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to get the values of the dynamically created EditTexts. You currently replace the instance of the EditText which each creation. Try the below code:

```
        List<EditText> editTextList = new ArrayList<>();

        private void setChoices() {

        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        int marginPixel = 1;
        int marginPixell = 5;
        float densityy =getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int marginDp = (int)(marginPixel * densityy);
        int margin = (int)(marginPixell * densityy);
        params.setMargins(marginDp, margin, marginDp, margin);


        int num= Integer.parseInt(choicesNumberEDT.getText().toString());


        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {

            EditText explanationED= new EditText(this);
            explanationED.setLayoutParams(params);
            editTextList.add(explanationED); //<-------new line here
            layout.addView(explanationED);
            explanationED.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
            explanationED.setHint("أكتب هنا.....");
            explanationED.setTextSize(14);
            explanationED.setId(i);
            float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int paddingDp = (int) (Const.paddingPixel * density);
            explanationED.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#B2E3CC"));
            explanationED.setPadding(paddingDp, paddingDp, paddingDp, paddingDp);

        }


    }


private EditText getText(int position) {
     return editTextList.get(position).getText().toString();
}
```

OR if you don't want to keep a list of the EditTexts, you can set a tag for each EditText you create using:

```
    editText.setTag("tag");
```

and later retrieve it using:

```
    layout.findViewWithTag("tag");
```

Comment: many many thannnnnnnnks,this is exactly what I want, i have updated private EditText getText(int position)to>>>>>private String getttext(int position).

Comment: No problem @Nanamedo, enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Each time in loop when you create a new object, you are assigning that to the same `EditText` object `explanationED` . This is why whenever you want to `getText()` from `explanationED` object you will always get the text of the last `EditText`.

 
For this scenario, 
Let's consider a `List` of `EditText` of length `N`, then give `id` to each of the list item - `EditText`. Now from these `ID's` you can get the value of any `EditText` object.

```
//e.g
list.get(i).getText().toString(); //getting value via index

//you may search for a specific Id.
for(EditText text: list) {
  if(text.getId() === MY_ID) {
   // do something..
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks ,samir , i have used The Hungry Androider''s solution