# How to get value from dynamically created edit text in Android?

Tags: android, dynamic, android-edittext, layout-inflater

How to get value from dynamically created EditText in Android?

This is my dynamic view (XML file)

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_waypoint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:hint="Way Points"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_waypoint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Find" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

And I am using `LayoutInflater` because I want perfect Designed layout which is not accomplish by me via `setLayoutParams` so this is the reason I am using `LayoutInflater`.

And here is my code:

```
  LayoutInflater l = getLayoutInflater();
                    final LinearLayout mainActivity = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamic);
                    final View view = l.inflate(R.layout.dynamic_layout_waypoints, null);
                    buttonWayPoints = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_waypoint);
                    editTextWayPoints = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_waypoint);
 mainActivity.addView(editTextWayPoints);
```

I am new to Android. Most of people suggest [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5923764/4696610) but it's not worked for me, the issue is when I implement this code my **ADD NEW EDIT TEXT BUTTON** not respond me.

This is how I am trying to get inserted value but it returns value of only last created edit text:

```
public Cursor getPerson(String Query) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
        return c;
    }
```

sb is `StringBuilder sb;`, w is `String w;`

```
String queryWayPoints = "select * from route_table where trip_id = " + t;
            Cursor s = myDb.getPerson(queryWayPoints);
            int count3 = s.getCount();
            for (int j = 0; j < count3; j++) {
                s.moveToNext();
                w = s.getString(s.getColumnIndex("waypoints"));
                // se.append(w + "." + "00");
            }
            trip_name.setText(n);
            trip_date.setText(d);
            sb.append(w);
        }
        trip_route.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Can you post the error log here

Comment: `editTextWayPoints.getText().toString()` should get you the text from your EditText.

Comment: Note the addition of shouting or voting advice tends to attract downvotes, and doubly so if you do both. Please refrain from adding either to your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, I didn't get what exactly your question is, still I'll try to help.
What exactly this code does is, on clicking the button on top an new layout(one that you wanted) will add to the activity screen at runtime, i.e an edittext with a button, and when you click on that button, A toast with the value of respective edittext will be shown. Hence solving the problem of **getting the value of dynamically added edittext**

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button generateET;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final LinearLayout myLinearLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamic);
        generateET = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generateBtn);
        generateET.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LayoutInflater l = getLayoutInflater();
                final View viewToAdd = l.inflate(R.layout.to_add, null);
                Button buttonWayPoints = (Button) viewToAdd.findViewById(R.id.btn_waypoint);
                final EditText editTextWayPoints = (EditText) viewToAdd.findViewById(R.id.et_waypoint);

                buttonWayPoints.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (editTextWayPoints.getText().toString() != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, editTextWayPoints.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No text found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                myLinearLay.addView(viewToAdd);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.techmahindra.stackques.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/generateBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="add editText To layout" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_below="@+id/generateBtn"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dynamic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
          ></LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**to_add.xml**(layout which will be inflated at runtime)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_waypoint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:hint="Way Points"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_waypoint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Find" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thax @ankitpurwar

Comment: Welcome @RayVaniya I hope this sorted out your problem.. Also, please upvote if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code. You're trying to add editTextWayPoints to mainActivity, but editTextWayPoints already has a parent, which is view. I think you should be adding view to mainActivity (mainActivity.addView(view)). Finally, to access the value of editTextWayPoints, you simply do editTextWayPoints.getText().toString();

Comment: i am able to create view but not able to get value, it return value of my last created Edit Text

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43527340/gettting-the-value-of-edittext-which-created-programmatically/43527683#43527683